# create a list of the attributes of files with cmdlet get-member

Tags: powershell

1)How to create a list of attributes of files with cmdlet get-member and then sort it by last write time?

2)Find total size of files with different extension(for examp total size for all *.html files)

I think the solution for the first task(second task is ok) should be like this(however it doesn't work)

```
 $a=get-childitem . -filter *.html
 $n=$a.Length
 do{
 $isnotsorted=0
 for($i=0;$i -lt ($n-1); $i++) {
  if ((get-member $a[$i]).LastWriteTime -lt (get-member $a[$i]).LastWRiteTime){
      $a[$i],$a[$i+1]=`
      $a[$i+1],$a[$i]
      $isnotsorted=$i+1
  }
 }
 $n=$isnotsorted
 }
 until ($n -eq 0)
 $a
```

Comment: As @BACON said, `Get-Member` will give you the object's properties and methods. Are you referring to these as Attributes? Normally attributes are considered properties of the file (Hidden, Read-Only, Archive etc..). These are accessed via an instance of the `System.IO.FileInfo` object which `Get-Member` doesn't create.

Comment: Perhaps it's the name `Get-Member` that's confusing?  `Get-Member` does not "get" the value of an object's member (method, parameter, or field).  `Get-Member` gets the definitions of the members from the object's type.  To retrieve the value of a particular member, you would use `$foo.Property` syntax, or cmdlets such as `Select-Object` or `Format-*`.  Note that in a list of files, assuming you haven't dynamically attached custom properties, `Get-Member` is going to return the same member definitions for every single file even though the values of those members will be different for each file.

Comment: So this is a learning exercise to implement bubble sort yourself, right?  You don't want to just change your code snippet to `get-childitem . -filter *.html | Sort-Object -Property 'LastWriteTime'`?  Because that *will* sort your list of `.html` files by their `LastWriteTime` property.  I think the problem is just that you need to change `(get-member $a[$i]).LastWriteTime` to `$a[$i].LastWriteTime`, & you're also comparing each file to itself (you need `$a[$i + 1]` in there).  As I explained above, `Get-Member` doesn't work like that and isn't needed here.  Just access the property directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need to use Get-Member to do this. You can use `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object`:

   ```
   dir C:\ -Force | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Sort LastWriteTime | Select FullName, Attributes
   ```
2. You can use `Group-Object` and `Measure-Object` to do this.

   ```
   ((dir D:\Software -Force -Filter *.html | Group Extension).Group | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1MB
   ```

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime` but here is how you would fix your bubble sort code. Remember `Get-Member` is not the right cmdlet to use to access a properties value.

```
$a = get-childitem -filter *.html
$n = $a.Length

do {
    $isnotsorted = 0
    for($i = 0; $i -lt ($n-1); $i++) {
        if ( ($a[$i]).LastWriteTime -lt ($a[$i + 1]).LastWRiteTime ) {
            $a[$i] , $a[$i+1] = $a[$i+1] , $a[$i]
            $isnotsorted = $i + 1
        }
    }   
    $n = $isnotsorted
} until ($n -eq 0)
$a
```

Another thing to note here is that the performance of this algorithm is much worse than just using `Sort-Object`. My music folder has 1355 files and the above finishes in 83 seconds. Using `Sort-Object` finishes in 1.7 seconds.

```
Measure-Command {
    get-childitem D:\shares\Music -rec -filter *.m4a | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Get-Member` to display the attributes of files.  Just use `Get-ChildItem` to get the contents of a directory and then pipe them to `Sort-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Sort-Object -Property 'LastWriteTime'
```

You can add the `-Recurse` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` to list child directories, and add `-Force` to list files with the `Hidden` attribute.  You can pipe all of this to a `Format-*` cmdlet if you want to display properties other than those displayed by the standard formatting for files and directories:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path `
    | Sort-Object -Property 'LastWriteTime' `
    | Format-Table -Property @('Attributes', 'FullName', 'CreationTime')
```

`Get-Member` can be used to determine which properties exist on a file or directory object.

You can use `Measure-Object` with the `-Sum` switch to add up the `Length` property of a collection of files:

```
$htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.html';
$measurement = $htmlFiles | Measure-Object -Property 'Length' -Sum;
$totalHtmlSize = $measurement.Sum;
```

To generate a table of the total size of each file type you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path `
    | Where-Object { $_ -is [IO.FileInfo]; } `
    | Group-Object -Property 'Extension' `
    | Select-Object `
        @{ Name = 'Extension'; Expression = 'Name' }, `
        @{ Name = 'TotalSize'; Expression = { `
            ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property 'Length' -Sum).Sum } `
        } `
    | Sort-Object -Property 'Extension';
```

That retrieves the contents of `$path`, filters it to only include files, groups the files by the `Extension` property, projects each group into an object with a property for the extension and a property for the total file size, then sorts the results by extension.

Comment: But the task was to use Get-Member.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for.  `Get-Member` will retrieve the properties and methods defined on a particular type.  To get the values of the properties on an *instance* of a type, you need to actually retrieve those instances with something like `Get-ChildItem`.  So, you want the properties of the files themselves, or you want to use `Get-Member` to retrieve the properties defined on the [`FileInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)?

Comment: I think that in this task I need to create list of attributes(maybe properties) with `Get-Member`, find attribute(property) `lastwritetime` and then sort all files by this attribute(but this property I need to get from list of properties).

Comment: Ok.  If you look at the first code sample in both my answer and @Andy Arismendi's answer, it shows you how to retrieve a list of files sorted by `LastWriteTime` and then you can display whatever properties of those files you want.  Do those not work for you?  It really is as easy as the short one-liners we've posted, and `Get-Member` is only going to make it harder or perhaps not even be helpful at all.  Since you know `LastWriteTime` is the property on which you want to sort, there's no need to "find" it with `Get-Member`.  Just specify `LastWriteTime` as the property to use and that's it.

Comment: I think the solution is - get list of *.html files with get-childitem then sort it with bubble sort by comparing attribute `lastwritetime`...Is it possible in PS?I mean bubble sort of the list. And attribute `lastwritetime` is getting from Get-Member for every file.

Comment: You want to group files by extension and then calculate the total file size of each group, or you want to display individual files with a particular extension sorted by their length?  You can implement your own sorting if and however you want, but PowerShell already provides the `Sort-Object` cmdlet to sort by arbitrary properties as we've demonstrated above.  All of this is possible in PowerShell, but you should definitely update your question to clarify what it is you want to do.  Also, please try the code samples we've provided and tell us specifically how they're not doing what you want.